Not Doubling Measure on $\mathbb R^d$
It feels like it should be obvious but I cannot see it.
Given the definition of a doubling measure to be a measure $\mu\in\mathcal M^+(\mathbb R^d)$ such that
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathrm{supp}(\mu)}\sup_{r>0}\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r/2))}<\infty.
$$
What is an example of a finite measure on $\mathbb R^d$ that is not doubling?
Conversely if the above doesn't exist:
Is it true that all finite measures on $\mathbb R^d$ are doubling?
It feels like they are all doubling but I cannot find a reference for it and proving it doesn't seem trivial.

Hint: try a bit harder to look for a counterexample, focusing on the case $d = 1$. If you get stuck, tell us what you have tried and what you think the obstacle is. For example: can you write down a non-finite measure that is not doubling? What's stopping you from adapting this example to be finite?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle\frac{4}{j^3},& x\in [j,j+1/4),\, j\in\mathbb{N}\\
\displaystyle\frac{4}{j^2} - \frac{4}{j^3},& x\in [j+1/4,j+1/2),\, j\in\mathbb{N}\\
0,& \text{elsewhere}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Now define the measure $\mu$ such that $d\mu = f d\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, that is,
$$ \mu(A) = \int_A f \, d\lambda, \quad \text{for }A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}). $$
Observe that
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\mu(\mathbb{R}) &= \displaystyle \int_\mathbb{R} f \, d\lambda,\\
                &= \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_{j}^{j/2} f d\lambda \\
                &= \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4}\frac{4}{j^3} + \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{4}{j^2}-\frac{4}{j^3}\right)\\
                &= \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2} < \infty,
\end{array}
$$
so the measure is finite.
Finally observe that
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle \frac{\mu(j, 1/2)}{\mu(j, 1/4)} &= \displaystyle \frac{1/j^2}{1/j^3}\\
                                &= \displaystyle j \longrightarrow \infty,
\end{array}
$$
so we found a sequence of points that when doubling the ratio of the balls around them, their measure gets infinitely bigger :)
Remark: the trick was simply to create a measure that for a sequence of points you get the property that doubling the measure creates two sequences, in this case $1/j^3$ and $1/j^2$, such that the sum of the bigger one converges. Then you just make a function that integrates these numbers for appropriate points in your space. This trick can be easily generalized for $d$ dimensions by defining the function as the same constants in balls instead of intervals.

Suppose that $\mu$ is a (Borel) probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the property that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a ball $B(x,r)$ centred at $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the support of $\mu$ and $r_0 > 0$ such that $\mu(B(x,r_0)) \in (1 - \epsilon, 1)$. For example, $\mu$ can be any absolutely continuous measure like standard normal. We look at the balls with another center containing and not containing this ball. That is, choose $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the support of $\mu$, $r > 0$ such that  $B(y, \frac{r}{2}) \cap B(x,r_0) = \emptyset$ and $B(x, r_0) \subseteq B(y, r)$. We see from assumptions that $\mu(B(y, \frac{r}{2})) < \epsilon$ and $\mu(B(y, r)) > 1 - \epsilon$. Therefore :
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mu(B(y, r))}{\mu(B(y, \frac{r}{2}))} > \frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}
\end{equation*}
If $\epsilon$ is chosen close enough to $0$, this is unbounded.
Some discrete measures do not satisfy the above hypothesis and would easily be seen as doubling according to your definition, the easiest being the point mass.
